# Sharepoint Task stored in non sharepoint Database

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I am looking at creating an application that will be a SharePoint application.  I want to store the tasks in my own database but still have them show up in the Calendar is this possible?

Comment: Can you explain why you need it to be in a different database?  We have done similar things for lists, but I'm not seeing the benefit for tasks.  Would a better idea be an event reciever on the task list that updates your database with the changes to the task?  That way, you don't break any SharePoint functionality, but can still do your custom processing in your database.

Comment: Again, move this comment to an actual answer, it counts as one!

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain why you need it to be in a different database? We have done similar things for lists, but I'm not seeing the benefit for tasks.

Would a better idea be an event reciever on the task list that updates your database with the changes to the task? That way, you don't break any SharePoint functionality, but can still do your custom processing in your database.

Comment: Well it is not really that we need the Task in our Database rather we have other Objects that need to appear in the calendar and show up like the tasks do in the calendar.  We are also looking at storing our Lists outside of SharePoint in SQL Server but that is a seperate issue.

Comment: You could look at using a "linked datasource" to include other items in the calendar view.  I did this a couple years ago to roll up different site and subsite calendars into one view.